# Connecting with php class to two mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange problem with my php class, which I use for connecting mysql database. I tested on localhost and it works great, but after uploading to server it behaves like that:

Here's connecting method from my class:

```
public function __construct($server, $user, $pass, $database, $encoding = "utf8") {
  self::$counter++;

  if($this->connect==null) {
    if(self::$counter>1) { $new_link = true; } else { $new_link = false; }
    if($this->connect = MySQL_Connect($server, $user, $pass, $new_link)) {
      mysql_select_db($database, $this->connect);
      $this->execute("SET NAMES '"+$encoding+"'");

      $this->server = $server;
      $this->user = $user;
      $this->password = $pass;
      $this->database = $database;
      $this->encoding = $encoding;

      return true;
    }
      else {
      echo "Error while connecting database!";
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the connecting code:

```
$SQL_server = "server1";
$SQL_user = "user1";
$SQL_pass = "pass1";
$Database = "database1";

$mysql = new mysql($SQL_server, $SQL_user, $SQL_pass, $Database);

$SQL_server2 = "server2";
$SQL_user2 = "user2";
$SQL_pass2 = "pass2";
$Database2 = "database2";

$mysql2 = new mysql($SQL_server2, $SQL_user2, $SQL_pass2, $Database2);
```

And the strange thing is, that error which I received is this: Access denied for user 'user2'@'%' to database 'database1'
It seems like variables mixed up or something like that, but I don't know why is it happening. When I delete the code for second connection, it works, but not together. I though it could by error with my static variable counter (which counts number of connections) and it may cause that $new_link attribute is not set to true, but even when I set it to true without any condition, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please post your entire mysql class on pastie.org or similar?

Comment: A constructor is not suppposed to return anything. This is unlikely to be the cause of this error, but remove `return true;` anyway.

Comment: With all the code you submitted, I do not get any errors. How did you define the var `self::$connect` ?

Comment: Here's the declaration: private static $counter = 0;

Comment: And here's the whole class (only simple class for my own purposes): http://pastie.org/private/1gzaojkia7isaasmaymqq

Answer (score -1):

I suffer from this problem before two days and i got solution for that is

Its server level issue not your code level

for that you have to set one line in your server

edit file named my.cnf it is in my /etc/my.cnf

max_connections = 500

Full File content is

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
max_allowed_packet=100M
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1
max_connections = 500

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid


long_query_time = 0
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysqld.slow.query.log

SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
log=/var/log/mysqld.general.log
/etc/my.cnf (END)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's solution for my problem, max_connections influences, well, max connections :) But it's not multiple connection to databases, is it? Or I'm wrong? ... And also I'm not able to change this variable on server, only on localhost